# Visual Basic update column is doing arthmetic in query

Tags: sql, vb.net, asp-classic

I have a page that displays results in a SQL database. And then I have another page that lets me edit whichever row I want to edit. One of the fields are dates. If added into the database through one of my pages it gets put in with the format (YEAR-MN-DY)(2014-04-11). When I go to UPDATE the date it then does arithmetic on the date. For example. If the date is currently 2014-04-11 and I update/change the date to 2010-01-01 it will replace the date with "2008" which is 2010 -1 - 1.

The variable is a string that is received through a HTML form.

```
strSQL = "UPDATE sales SET cust_id = " & intcust_id & ", agent_id = " & intagent_id & ", saledate = " & strsaledate & " WHERE sale_id = " & intsale_id & ""
```

Is the SQL query I am running.

Also, the DATE is VARCHAR2 in the database and used as a string throughout my VB code. I kept it this way because not everyone enters the date the same and this is for simplicity.

Comment: If you want Dates to act like Dates, use a Date datatype.  The code which creates `strsaledate` may be the culprit doing the subtraction.

Comment: @JohnJohnson Date input: [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57(v=vs.110).aspx), Date output: [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) And please remove the irrelevant asp-classic tag from this and your previous question.

Comment: Your update statement is missing single quotes around your date value.  saledate ='" & strsaledate & "' WHERE

Comment: @John do your webpages end with the extension *.asp?

Comment: @WorkSmarter, The issue was indeed with the missing single quotes! Is this for a date only thing? Or should it always be used regardless of data type? However, thank you for your help! And they end with .aspx.

Comment: [Data Type Summary for Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx)  If you put your dates inside ticks, they are not dates, but text. `GoTo Comment 1:`

Comment: @JohnJohnson [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Comment: @John Use single quotes for strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subtraction is occurring because the date is not being interpreted as a date, but as a number because it is missing its quotes.

**Before**

```
strSQL = "UPDATE sales SET cust_id = " & intcust_id & ", agent_id = " & intagent_id & ", saledate = " & strsaledate & " WHERE sale_id = " & intsale_id & ""
```

**After**

```
strSQL = "UPDATE sales SET cust_id = " & intcust_id & ", agent_id = " & intagent_id & ", saledate ='" & strsaledate & "' WHERE sale_id = " & intsale_id & ""
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from WorkSmarter tackles the problem. I think however you should not use string concatenation.  It is wide open to sql-injections and it is indeed much nicer, simpler and less error prone to use parameters. Something like

```
strSQL = "UPDATE sales SET cust_id = @custid, agent_id = @agentid, saledate = @salesdate WHERE sale_id = @saleid"
set custid = cmd.CreateParameter("@custid", adChar,adInput,10, incust_id)
set agentid = cmd.CreateParameter("@cagentid", adInteger,adInput,0, ) ...
```

I'm asuming you have an ADODB.Command by the name of cmd. By doing it like this you are making your code a lot safer and, in my opinion, more readable since you don't have to worry about quotes and single quotes all the time. There is a clear distinction between the sql command and the params/values involved.
You can find good documentation on parameter on http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_comm_createparameter.asp